# Dynamic applicationpath

Tags: java, jax-rs

A new application of ours uses multi-tenancy with multiple database. By providing a tenant id in the URL, we can select the right datasource.

But by using that kind of method, the namespace of the URL becomes dynamic (e.g.: instead of `/api` the url changes to `/{id}/api`). So is it possible to use a dynamic [@ApplicationPath](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/ApplicationPath.html)?

Just as it is possible to use a variable in the [@Path](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/Path.html) annotation, could I write something like `@ApplicationPath("/tenants/{id}/api")`?

Comment: I don't think you can have path parameters in the `@ApplicationPath`. But you can start the `@Path` with a path parameter: `@Path("/{id}/tenants")`

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin: Yeah, I also begin to think that using a variable within the `@ApplicationPath` is just not supported (I don't find any mentions about this issue at the Internet anyway).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems applicationpath does not support dynamic segments. In the end we fixed it by using [sub-resources](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2496):

**Config**

```
@ApplicationPath("tenants")
public class TenantConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public TenantConfig(ObjectMapper mapper) {
        //set provider + add mapper

        register(TenantsController.class);
    }
}
```

**TenantsController**

```
@Path("/{id}/api")
public class TenantsController {

   //register all your controllers including path here

    @Path("/somethings")
    public Class<SomethingController> something() {
        return SomethingController.class;
    }
}
```

**SomethingController**

```
@Component
//Don't use @Path, as path info is already defined in the TenantsController
public class SomethingController {
    //do your stuff here;

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}") //Path for this example would be /tenants/{id}/api/somethings/{id}
    public JsonApiResult get(@PathParam("id") int id) {
       //retrieve one something
    }
}
```